# changing the default drawer icon (Hamburger)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar

I want to change the default icon which opens the drawer. Is there a way that I can do it? I searched in question and I couldn't solve it. Here is my Navigation Drawer class which I instanciate from it in other classes where I need fragment.

```
public class navigation_drawer extends Fragment {

public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "testpref";
public static final String KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "user_learned_drawer";

private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawer_toggle;
private DrawerLayout my_drawer_layout;

private View container_view;

private boolean m_userLearnedDrawer;
private boolean m_fromSavedInstanceState;

public navigation_drawer() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    m_userLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(
            readFromPreferences( getActivity() , KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER , "false" )
    );

    if( savedInstanceState != null )
    {
        m_fromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
}

public void setUp( int fragmentId , DrawerLayout dl , final Toolbar toolbar )
{

    container_view = getActivity().findViewById( fragmentId );
    my_drawer_layout = dl;
    drawer_toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( getActivity() , dl , toolbar ,
            R.string.drawer_open , R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if( ! m_userLearnedDrawer )
            {
                m_userLearnedDrawer = true;
                saveToPreferences( getActivity() , PREF_FILE_NAME ,
                        m_userLearnedDrawer + "" );
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView)
        {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item !=null && item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home)
            {
                if (my_drawer_layout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.RIGHT))
                {
                    my_drawer_layout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else
                {
                    my_drawer_layout.openDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset)
        {
            if( slideOffset < 0.1 ) {
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
    };

    /*
    if( !m_userLearnedDrawer && !m_fromSavedInstanceState )
    {
        my_drawer_layout.openDrawer( container_view );
    }
    */

    my_drawer_layout.setDrawerListener( drawer_toggle );

    my_drawer_layout.post(
            new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    drawer_toggle.syncState();
                }
            }
    );
}

public static void saveToPreferences( Context con , String preferenceName , String preferenceValue)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = con.getSharedPreferences( PREF_FILE_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString( preferenceName , preferenceValue );
    editor.apply();
}

public static String readFromPreferences( Context con , String preferenceName , String preferenceValue)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = con.getSharedPreferences( PREF_FILE_NAME , Context.MODE_PRIVATE );
    return sp.getString( preferenceName , preferenceValue );
}
}
```

But when I put this code `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.picture);`
 inside onDrawerOpened it shows the default Hamburger icon but when I slide or Click on icon it changes to my picture and it replaces the default icon. 
And here is the class where I instanciate the navigation drawer class.

```
public class welcome extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

    getWindow().getDecorView().setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);

    my_toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(my_toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    navigation_drawer myNav = (navigation_drawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);

    myNav.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.welcome_layout), my_toolbar);

}
```

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? If you want your image to always be the icon, just move the `toolbar.setNavigationIcon()` call your out of `onDrawerOpened()` to directly in the `setUp()` method.

Comment: I did it but it didn't work

Comment: I want to replace it for always with the default one

Comment: Oops, yeah, sorry. My bad. You need to call it after you call `syncState()` on the toggle, so move it to after that in the `run()` method of the `Runnable` you're posting on the `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: thanks that solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to call it after you call syncState() on the toggle, so move it to after that in the run() method of the Runnable.